# Bookmarklet - force select from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, bookmarklet

I have a web page that I'd like to automate with a bookmarklet.

It has a drop-down that lets the user select time range types: minutes, hours, days. I want to select Days in the bookmarklet code, but I don't know how to go about these `data-bind` attributes in knockout:

The HTML looks like this:

```
<span class="btn-group">
    <button class="dropdown-toggle" tabindex="-1" data-bind="disable: settings.disabled">
        <span data-bind="text: settings.offsetUnits">Days</span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-bind="foreach: settings.offsetUnitsChoices">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.selectUnits">Minutes</a></li>

        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.selectUnits">Hours</a></li>

        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.selectUnits">Days</a></li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you fire a jquery click event on the element in the list you would like to select it will trigger the $parent.selectUnits function, which should select the element. See an example below.

```
$('ul > li:nth-child(6) > a').click()
```

```js
var pageViewModel = {
  selectUnits: function(itemClicked) {
   alert(`You selected ${itemClicked}`);
    pageViewModel.settings.offsetUnits(itemClicked);
  },
 settings: {
   offsetUnits: ko.observable(0),
    offsetUnitsChoices: [5, 15, 30, 45]
  }
};



ko.applyBindings(pageViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>



<span class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span data-bind="text: `${settings.offsetUnits()} Units`"></span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-bind="foreach: settings.offsetUnitsChoices">
        <li><a href="#" data-bind="text: `${$data} Minutes`, click: $parent.selectUnits"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-bind="text: `${$data} Hours`, click: $parent.selectUnits"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-bind="text: `${$data} Days`, click: $parent.selectUnits"></a></li>
    </ul>
</span>


<a href="javascript:$('ul > li:nth-child(6) > a').click()">My bookmark to select the 6th item in the dropdown</a>
```

Comment: I took your idea and played with it until it worked: `$(".dropdown-menu",".offsetPicker").find("li:nth-child(3)")[0].children[0].click()`

Comment: Nice! If you have problems finding the selector in the future here is a tip: in Chrome right click on the element in and select "inspect" (this will open dev tools). Then you can right click on the html element you want a select "copy" > "Copy selector" now the exact selector needed to select the element is in your clipboard.